# I have a good memory

Tags: indefinite-article

> I have a good memory.

It means "I am good at memorizing things".

But can't it mean "I have a good recollection?"

And what would "I have good memory" mean?

To eliminate the confusion.

**I don't have a good memory, but I have a good memory of her.**

Comment: What do you mean by "have a good recollection"? How is that functionally different from "have a good memory"?

Comment: 1 an ability as possessed by an individual: to have a good memory. = I memorize things well. 2 I have a good memory of my childhood. 1 and 2 mean different things

Comment: @user1425 It can mean both, but it usually means "I remember many things (whether or not I'm trying to do so on purpose)." Even if I've never tried to "memorize" something, I can still know that I have a good memory if I often remember things others don't.

Comment: Number 2 is simply an example of number 1. All you are saying is that you are good at remembering things, whether it's things in general or in particular is not relevant.

Comment: No, Ronald Sole. It's not what I am saying. "I have a good memory." and "I have a good memory of her" mean different things.

Comment: Esther, why not "I have good memory"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is potentially ambiguous.

But in practice, English speakers would hardly ever say *I have a good memory* to mean remembering something welcome. They might say *It is a good memory*, or more likely *I have good memories*, or *There are good memories*.

*I have a good memory* is almost always used in your sense 1, and it would take a lot of context to override that sense.

Comment: Would it be wrong "I have good memory"?

Comment: On the face of it, that should be perfectly grammatical, but I can't imagine a native English speaker saying it, @user1425. I guess that when we say "I have a good memory" we are talking about our own memory, and so it is a singular thing - the same word as we are talking about our recollection of a specific experience. We use _memory_ as an uncountable only in the abstract, not normally when referring to an indvidual's memory.

Comment: Thank you. Strangely enough, but you say "I have good health" without "a".

Comment: @user1425: you're right, except that _I am in good health_ is much more likely than _I have good health_.  Other words that might be used without an article there are _balance_, _poise_, _sense_, _intelligence_, _skill_. But not _memory_.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide the context, that is what it would mean,

> I have a good memory of the day we went to the beach.

However, this is not particularly fluent, as there are better ways to express the same idea. You could use a more precise adjective

> I have a clear memory of the day we went to the beach.

or you could use "remember" or "recollect":

> I remember the day we went to the beach very well.

So I'd prefer

> I don't have a good memory, but I remember her well!